# spinner with custom layout getting overlap in first item, just in android 5

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a spinner with custom layout, in all android version except 5 it looks normal **BUT** just in android 5 the first item getting overlap.
version like 4.4, 4.2 the spinner looks normal.

here is a picture of what is happening:

[image: Android 5]  [image: android 4.4]

the left is android 5 and right is android 4.4

i'm filling spinner with this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.language_name, R.layout.lang_filter_base_layout);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.lang_filter_item_layout);
        languageSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the `lang_filter_item_layout` :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:textAlignment="inherit"
          android:textColor="@color/medium_gray"
          android:textSize="@dimen/language_spinner_text_size"/>
```

the `lang_filter_item_layout`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textColor="@color/medium_gray"
          android:textSize="@dimen/language_spinner_text_size"
          android:padding="@dimen/language_spinner_item_padding"
```

the spinner in my fragment:

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/language_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:popupBackground="@color/light_gray"/>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set android:overlapAnchor="false" on your Spinner or use an opaque popup background.

Comment: tnx alot, works perfectly.